# How to build python package with pdm and include external dependencies

Tags: python, package, external-dependencies, pdm

I'm trying to build a wheel using the PDM tool, however when I build the package, external dependencies (eg semver) are not included. This means whoever uses my tool, will need to install these dependencies as well. Is there a way to package the external dependencies together with my package using PDM?

Comment: Are your external dependencies listed in `requirement.txt` ? Have you tried `pdm add <dependency>` (see [PEP508](https://peps.python.org/pep-0508/) to format dependencies manually if you want)

Comment: The dependencies are listed in `pyproject.toml` and indeed i add them with `pdm add` however, when I do `pdm build`, the dist file don't contain those dependencies

Comment: Yeah it's normal, a package contain itself plus only the references for other packages. But when you try to install it, it should recursively get all dependencies